# How to run TA-Lib on multiple tickers in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

I have a pandas dataframe named **idf** with data from 4/19/21 to 5/19/21 for 4675 tickers with the following columns: symbol, date, open, high, low, close, vol

```
|index  |symbol |date       |open   |high   |low        |close  |vol    |EMA8|EMA21|RSI3|RSI14|
|-------|-------|-----------|-------|-------|-----------|-------|-------|----|-----|----|-----|
|0      |AACG   |2021-04-19 |2.85   |3.03   |2.8000     |2.99   |173000 |    |     |    |     |
|1      |AACG   |2021-04-20 |2.93   |2.99   |2.7700     |2.85   |73700  |    |     |    |     |
|2      |AACG   |2021-04-21 |2.82   |2.95   |2.7500     |2.76   |93200  |    |     |    |     |
|3      |AACG   |2021-04-22 |2.76   |2.95   |2.7200     |2.75   |56500  |    |     |    |     |
|4      |AACG   |2021-04-23 |2.75   |2.88   |2.7000     |2.84   |277700 |    |     |    |     |
|...    |...    |...        |...    |...    |...        |...    |...    |    |     |    |     |
|101873 |ZYXI   |2021-05-13 |13.94  |14.13  |13.2718    |13.48  |413200 |    |     |    |     |
|101874 |ZYXI   |2021-05-14 |13.61  |14.01  |13.2200    |13.87  |225200 |    |     |    |     |
|101875 |ZYXI   |2021-05-17 |13.72  |14.05  |13.5500    |13.82  |183600 |    |     |    |     |
|101876 |ZYXI   |2021-05-18 |13.97  |14.63  |13.8300    |14.41  |232200 |    |     |    |     |
|101877 |ZYXI   |2021-05-19 |14.10  |14.26  |13.7700    |14.25  |165600 |    |     |    |     |
```

I would like to use ta-lib to calculate several technical indicators like EMA of length 8 and 21, and RSI of 3 and 14.

I have been doing this with the following code after uploading the file and creating a dataframe named **idf**:

```
ind = pd.DataFrame()
tind = pd.DataFrame()
for ticker in idf['symbol'].unique():
    tind['rsi3'] = ta.RSI(idf.loc[idf['symbol'] == ticker, 'close'], 3).round(2)    
    tind['rsi14'] = ta.RSI(idf.loc[idf['symbol'] == ticker, 'close'], 14).round(2)    
    tind['ema8'] = ta.EMA(idf.loc[idf['symbol'] == ticker, 'close'], 8).round(2)    
    tind['ema21'] = ta.EMA(idf.loc[idf['symbol'] == ticker, 'close'], 21).round(2)    
    ind = ind.append(tind)
    tind = tind.iloc[0:0]

idf = pd.merge(idf, ind, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Is this the most efficient way to doing this?

If not, what is the easiest and fastest way to calculate indicator values and get those calculated indicator values into the dataframe **idf**?

Prefer to avoid a for loop if possible.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this way fast enough for your usecase? If so, you may need to better describe your usecase. If the question is: can TA-Lib calculate two EMA indicators with different timeperiod during a single pass throw data - no, it can't. Is this possible to implement on your own? - yes. But you better to implement this in C/C++ and create python wrappers. Bcs TA-Lib is written in C and you just call wrapper for it. So it's not guaranteed that own smart EMA implementation will be faster then TA-lib.

Comment: And if your performance issues may be solved by saving states of calculated indicators and resuming their calculation when new data arrives you may consider [TA-Lib RT](https://github.com/trufanov-nok/ta-lib-rt) fork,

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response as I havent received any notifications about your comments. I have 4675 tickers and may get more tickers probably. Running a for loop and calculating a bunch of indicators in on a daily basis can be very time consuming. Having said that, I have to explore TA-Lib RT fork as I havent considered saving states of calculated indicators. Will explore TA-Lib RT and get back to you if I have any further questions. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am a bit late, but feel free to check this [here](https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta#custom-strategy-without-multiprocessing)

Answer (score 0):

```
rsi = lambda x: talib.RSI(idf.loc[x.index, "close"], 14) 
idf['rsi(14)'] = idf.groupby(['symbol']).apply(rsi).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.